# Opencv houghLines not detecting lines

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am trying to filter an image using Hough lines but something just isn't working.

I created the following subroutine, which was copy pasted without modification from the documentation:

```
def FilterLines(img):
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(img,1,np.pi/180,200)
    blank_image = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    if (lines is None):
        return blank_image
    for rho,theta in lines[0]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

        cv2.line(blank_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),255,1)

    return blank_image
```

I then give it the following test image:
[image]

But the function [image]outputs:

So it kinda detected a couple of lines at the bottom and nothing else.

Why can;t the function detect lines in such a simple image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line`for rho,theta in lines[0]:`. You are using only one line, the first one `line[0]`.

You need to change the for loop like this:

```
    for x in range(0, len(lines)):    
        for rho, theta in lines[x]:
```

The whole code then looks like this (with extra debug statements commented out, after I put them in for testing):

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

#path = os.path("D:\")
img = cv2.imread("D:\\oV1PG.png")

#cv2.imshow('image',img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#print(img)

'''height, width, channel = img.shape[:3]
size = img.size

print(height, width, channel, size)'''


if img is not None:
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(img, 1, np.pi / 180, 100)


    blank_image = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)

    for x in range(0, len(lines)):    
        for rho, theta in lines[x]:
            a = np.cos(theta)
            b = np.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            x1 = int(x0 + 1000 * (-b))
            y1 = int(y0 + 1000 * (a))
            x2 = int(x0 - 1000 * (-b))
            y2 = int(y0 - 1000 * (a))

            cv2.line(blank_image, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), 255, 1)
            print(x1, y1, x2, y2)

        print("\n")

    cv2.imshow("out", blank_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    print("empty img. Cannot read file")
```

This is how the output looks on my PC:

[image]

Comment: So hough will have a tendency to xtend the ines all the way to the origin (0,0)?

Comment: This function takes two more parameters, `cv2.HoughLines(img, 1, np.pi / 180, 100)`, which as per [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) are `cv2.HoughLines(img, 1, np.pi / 180, 100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)`. Maybe playing with them could produce a different result. But honestly, I didn't look into that, as it was not the original question here.

p.s. the lines are not extended to the origin (0,0) in any case. Look at the vertical lines. They don't tend to go to the origin. Nor do any of the horizontal lines.

Comment: Also as per the [hough transform docs](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html), you can play with the threshold also. It is `100` in your code. Increasing it would reduce the number of lines. But this may also remove legitimate lines. One would have to play with the parameters a little to get the best result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. There is a conflict in openCV versions which doesn't let us perform the above operation in that way.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
for line in lines:
    rho = line[0][0]
    theta = line[0][1]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```